# Dealing with lavalier mic bleed in post

Tags: lavalier

Greetings venerable masters, able journeyman, and avid apprentices like myself.

I'm cutting and mixing the sound I recorded for a very small television interview program in PT8. I ran hardwired Sanken COS-11 lavaliers into a SD302 mixer and Fostex FR2LE. Host was recorded to one track, guest to the other.

When each dedicated DX track overlaps one another during moments of mutual interjection, laughter, or banter, the mic bleed sounds jarring against the close perspective gotten while each participant is speaking solo.

Is there any way to keep both lavalier mic's close perspective at the same time? Or would the recommendation be to prioritize the information by cutting (keep the DX track with speaking, while editing out the other participants simultaneous non-critical laughter, etc. on the other track).

Distance between the speakers is about 2-3 feet.

Much obliged, and thanks for such a wealth of information!
atheisticmystic

Comment: apply pressure until the bleeding stops.

Comment: It sounds like you are getting a bit of summing. Have you tried inverting the phase of one of the channels? 

Comment: @Bluesman, I used audiosuite-other-invert, and it sounds resolved. Much obliged to you for sharing your time and experience!

@Ryan, I love the COS-11!!!

@VCProd........Im sorry to say...we lost the patient.


Comment: @athiesticmystic, Sorry, I just realized that I misread your post.  For some silly reason I thought you were leaving both mics open all the time, and that the jarring bit was due to phase weirdness.  Mea culpa.

Comment: @atheisticmystic Glad I could be of help.